# Spring expression case insensitive

Tags: c#

I am using spring.core library. And trying to evaluate the expression with case insensitive.

```
class myobj
{
    public string test { set; get; }
}

var exp = Spring.Expressions.Expression.Parse("test=='me'");
var result = exp.GetValue(new myobj { test = "ME" });
```

Basically, I want the result to be true.

Is there a way to tell the expression that I want to ignore the case when doing the comparison.

Comment: Not necessarily the best of doing it, but you set your `get` on your `test` property to always return a lower or uppercase string. This would mean you need a backing field. Something like this: `private string _test;` then `public string test {get => _test.ToLower(); set => _test = value; }`

Comment: I see your point. But I cant do that, the expression test=='me' is input by the user, and the object is containing the info that I shouldn't change and is not guarantee to be upper case